Accessing the FM 19kHz Pilot?
How can one attach an oscilloscope probe to the mono mode output of an FM station to pick up the 19kHz pilot (normally used for stereo)?
Is it expected that FM tuners such as the RDA5807 will, in mono mode, pass the 19kHz band through?  If not, what is a good fallback short of a discrete component tuner?  Or is there?

please refer to the RDA5807 datasheet

Since RDA5807M is an "all-digital" system ... it seems that you can't.

I set the oscilloscope to 50us/division (20kHz) and attached the oscilloscope probe to the speaker output of an FM radio based on the QN8035 FM tuner, that I had hard-wired to monomode (solder joint short).  During dead air, I got what is almost certainly a residual 19kHz pilot tone.

This is the exact chip:

This is the receiver:

